# error using Corpus in R (wordcloud)

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

I am new to R and trying wordcloud using a text file separated by spaces. I have installed `tm` and `tmap` packages. I am getting following errors:

> Error: could not find function "Corpus"
>   Error: could not find function "tm_map"

Can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to load the packages also into your session via

`library(tm)`
`library(tmap)`

Then the function `tm()` is available for you. 
Another possibilty is

`tm::tm_map()`

This calls **R** to take the function `tm_map()` from package `tm`.

Comment: The [`tmap` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/index.html) is almost certainly unnecessary here - although I don't know what the content of the wordcloud is supposed to be. It may be better to suggest `library(wordcloud)` in addition to `library(tm)`.

Comment: Thanks @J_F . I have loaded the the three libraries tm, wordcloud and SnowballC and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @RHertel. I have loaded the the three libraries tm, wordcloud and SnowballC and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I tried after installing below and it worked for me:

```
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/tm_0.5-10.zip",repos=NULL)
library(tm)
```

Comment: elaborate your answer